# Can´t boot debian after installation

Tags: linux, debian

I am trying to use Debian as a dual boot with Windows 10, the installation process was fine, without errors and I am able to access GRUB and select Debian, which starts but after some lines of text, the screen goes black and shows a message saying "not supported". My PC has a GeForce GTX 1060 from EVGA and runs the screen through HDMI

Comment: What Version of Debian please?

Comment: It might be an error with the grub installation. With which filesystem did you format your partitions?  Does your linux boot partition have the 'boot flag'  set?

Comment: The version is Debian Jessie

Comment: File system was formatted in ext4

Comment: Stroke Ctrl+Alt+F2 together and login if possible. `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display"`  As far as I read you need nvidia-driver from backports.